# Передать картинку из list в новое activity

Tags: android, listview, activity

Нужно передать картинку  из list в следующие activity, через intent никак не передает.

Активити списка:

```
public class Spisok extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Лист для продуктов
    ListView listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productsList);
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);
    listV.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemList());
}
    class ItemList implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;

            TextView tv = (TextView)   vg.findViewById(R.id.productListName);
            TextView text = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.productListText);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) vg.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImage); //Картинка которую нужно передать

            Toast.makeText(Spisok.this, tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Spisok.this, ActivityTwo.class);

            intent.putExtra("text", text.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("fname", tv.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Активити куда нужно передать:

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {


  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.products_sign);

    TextView productName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productListName1);
    TextView productText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productListText1);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImage1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
    String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text");
    productName1.setText(fName);
    productText.setText(text1);

    }
}
```

Comment: сохрани в память телефона, а во второй активити загрузи. Вот статья в помощь https://habrahabr.ru/post/132875/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразуйте изображение в Bitmap и ByteArrayOutputStream потом отправьте через Intent вот пример кода:

```
// Первое активити
    Intent intent = new Intent(Spisok.this, ActivityTwo.class);
    Bitmap bitmam; 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmam.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
    i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
    startActivity(i);

// Второе активити
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap bitmam = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);        
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmam);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь преобразовал при помощи строчки
         
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();